# Not getting data from sql server 2014 in asp.net using linq?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq

I'm trying to get data from sql server using linq and then verifying it. But it is not getting data from sql server. I also write a function for sending data into sql server that store data properly.

**The main problem is that sign funtion(httppost) not getting data in var user from sql server?**

```
 private DB db = new DB(); //Database context

 public ActionResult Index()
 {
    return View();
 }

 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Sign()
 {
  return View();
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Sign(Login l)
 {
    var user = db.Logins.Where(s => s.Username == l.Username && s.Password           
                               == l.Password).FirstOrDefault();

  return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");


   }
```

Comment: Do you get any exception? Is username and password match exists? Make sure you have considered case sensitivity for both username and password.

Comment: no exception. simply not getting data in var user. I checked it by point break.

Comment: i also write a function for adding data in sql server which add data properly. but not getting from database

Comment: Did you verify database record with case sensitivity?

Comment: yes i verify that no case sensitvity issue.

Comment: Use SQL server profiler to catch the call, to ensure you are sending call to right database and use that query to test if it returns results.

Comment: Also try first without any `where` clause at all and see if user variable shows any data in quick watch on enumerating it. Also check connection string and see if you are pointing to the right database.

Comment: try comparing only by username without password in linq

Comment: How how to use SQL Server profiler.. Adil

Comment: Connection is checked it twice:                               
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DB" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SHAN\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=UmairDb;user id=sa;password=***************;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: data is inserted in database but not retreied.............